# Linq Object as ComboBox DataSource

Tags: linq, combobox

I have a ComboBox being bind to LINQ object as below.

```
    Dim LearnTypeList = context.LearnTypes.OrderBy(Function(a) a.LearnType).ToList()
    dlLearnedAbout.DataSource = LearnTypeList
    dlLearnedAbout.DisplayMember = "LearnType"
    dlLearnedAbout.ValueMember = "LearnType"
```

I am not able to use Index of Items to find Item with matching text as below .

MessageBox.Show(dlLearnedAbout.Items.IndexOf("Website"))

This always returns -1 even if its there inside the table and dropdown.Is it because the Item bound to the Dropdown is of type "LearnTypes ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

IndexOf("Website") is looking through the list for an item of type String.  your list doesn't contain strings though - it contains objects of whatever type you have in context.LearnTypes.  that's why you are getting -1 (aka item not found)

Comment: How will I be able to find that than ? Use a for loop ? Or create a dummy object of type "Learn Type" ?